# WCF selfhost service: Change max Uri length

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, uri, maxlength

I have built a WCF based REST service which is self hosted. If I append the URI by filter parameters it happens that the URI gets very long which results the service not accepting the query any more and responding:

```
HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long
```

By playing around I found out that the service accepts 15k characters (15360). Is there any way to extend the excepted URI length?

Comment: If your URI has the potential of being exceedingly long, why not switch from GET to POST?

Comment: Switching to POST means that I can't use the WCF integrated caching logic as WCF only evaluates response's ETag and set request's IfNoneMatch for GET requests.

Comment: There is a requestLimits element in the web.config that might be worth playing with, however their defaults don't match what you're seeing.
Scroll down to the "Configuration" section on this page:
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits

Comment: @denvercoder9 Might be worth..but how / where to add in a self hosted (ServiceHost) service?